# Fetch Microsoft 365 Outlook Emails from Gmail

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have two E-mail accounts: a **free Gmail** and **University E-mail account**. What I would like to achieve is to fetch my University Emails from my Gmail account and never have to login into my Email account again. My school uses Microsoft 365.
I have been trying to use Gmail's Email importer from the Settings Tab but I always get this error:

[image: screenshot-gmail]

**Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password.**
What I do not understand is that this Mail Importer feature works on Gmail app on my Android Smartphone using the **Exchange** option. Nevertheless, Importing my University E-mails from the Webmail Settings never do. I have also asked the IT Support Department of my Uni but they only said that they do not have any idea.

Comment: Did you find a way to make this work?

Answer (score -1):

This setting is for Gmail, you should contact Gmail support team.
If you want to use Gmail account to receive Office 365 emails, you could set to forward Office 365 message to your Gmail account.

Forward my Office 365 email to a different email account

https://sg.godaddy.com/en/help/forward-my-office-365-email-to-a-different-email-account-20078

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7012a64f-74e6-43b4-9ec4-2dbfcec62fa9/forwarding-emails-block-sign-in-under-o365?forum=Office2016setupdeploy