# How to use GMail UI to access Exchange On Line email account

Tags: gmail, exchange, gmail-imap

I have found many forum entries, replies and articles on this or similar subjects, but most are kind of old and no longer apply while others do not address/answer directly the question.

See for example [Fetch Microsoft 365 Outlook Emails from Gmail](https://superuser.com/q/1556076/166664) : the OP asked for the same question but the answer is to forward emails from one account to another.

What we want is: use the Gmail web user interface to directly access and directly use a corporate Exchange On Line (EoL) email account.

We do **not** want to sync an EoL account with a Gmail account, we do **not** want to forward emails from an EoL account to a Gmail account; **in this scenario there is no Gmail account** - we just want to use the Gmail web user interface.

Please refer to the picture in  [Fetch Microsoft 365 Outlook Emails from Gmail](https://superuser.com/q/1556076/166664) - is there any way to answer the prompts in this form so that we can access the EoL account? Or any other way to do it?

I understand that I may need to configure the EoL for IMAP and POP - that is fine I have control on that server (although it's not clear where to set this up in the new Exchange On Line Admin site).

Perhaps this cannot be done and my users who prefer this Gmail web UI will have to switch to another mail client?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

I have 'User' already configured in Windows Mail (or Outlook) to send/receive email from his 'Exchange on Line' (EoL) account.
I want 'User' to be able to send/receive emails from his Exchange mail box using the Gmail web UI.

Note: In Azure AD, setting 'Enable Security Default' should be OFF (I haven't tested with this setting ON). Also, in 'Microsoft 365 admin center', the User's 'Mail-> Manage email apps' should allow for Pop and Authenticated SMTP.

1- In Google Mail, login as the Organization's administrator. Click 'Settings', click 'Manage this organization'.

2- Click 'Menu->Apps->Google Workspace->Gmail'.

3- Click 'Hosts' (second option as of today).

4- Click 'ADD ROUTE'. Enter anything for 'Name' (eg 'Exchange on Line'). Select 'Single Host'. Enter 'smtp.office365.com' for the host name. Select port 587. Check all 4 options. Click 'Test TSL connection'. Click 'SAVE'.

5- This is the bummer: you need to wait for this change to kick in. The message says 'up to 24 hours', me I had to wait about 1 hour.

Now configure Gmail to receive emails:

6- In Gmail, logout as the Administrator and log back in as the User. Goto 'Settings-> See all settings'. Click 'Accounts' and then 'Add another email address'.

7- Enter the User's full Exchange email address. Uncheck 'Treat as an alias'. Click 'Next Step'.

8- If you did not wait long enough (see step 5) you will get a message 'You must send through mydomainname.ca SMTP servers when you send as user@mydomainname.ca. However, this functionality is not available for your account. Please contact your domain administrator for more information.'.

9- If you did wait long enough, you will get a dialog asking for SMTP Server, Username and Password. Enter 'smtp.office365.com', the User's full exchange email address in 'Username' and the Exchange password. Select (check) 'Secured connection using TLS'. Click 'Add Account'.

10- After a moment you will get 'An email ... code was sent to [the Exchange email address]'. Check the email (in Windows Mail), and copy/paste the verification code.

11- You will then end back on the 'Mail Settings->Account' page and the new email address will be displayed. If you want/need click 'Make Default' on this address.

Now you can send mails, but you cannot receive any.

12- Under 'Check mail from other accounts' click 'Add a mail account'.

13- Enter the User's full Exchange email address and click 'Next'.

14- A dialog box will display. Enter the full Exchange email address in the Username, enter the password; in the 'POP server' field enter 'outlook.office365.com' and select port 995. Select (check) 'Always use a secure connection (SSL) when retrieving mail'.

15- Click 'Add Account'. You should receive an email (in Windows mail) with a link to click to confirm your settings. Click 'Confirm'.

16- To test: from another email address: send an email to the Google address and send another email to the Exchange address: in the Gmail web UI you should receive both emails.

17- To test: in the Gmail web UI sent an email to that other email account: that account should receive it and its should be set as 'sent from [the exchange account] (if you clicked 'Make Default' in step 11).

Comment: Thanks for your kind sharing, could your account work normally now?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I just now set it up , tested sending and receiving and it works.

Here's what I did:

Select the gear(settings) icon in gmail, then click on "See all settings", then click on "Accounts and Import"

You have to setup SMTP and POP3 here. So click on "Add another Email Address" first. By following the prompts I was able to setup SMTP on port 587 with TLS. This is to an Exchange server that I manage.  Google may send You a confirmation email with a confirmation code that you have to enter to complete the setup. once done I am able to send through my exchange server as my account on that exchange server.

Next I setup POP3. To do this I again went to the same settings page by selecting the gear(settings) icon in gmail, then click on "See all settings", then click on "Accounts and Import". Then I clicked on "Add A Mail Account"  I then provided the settings on my Exchange server for POP3, There is a check box for SSL and a check box for "leave a copy on the server" or words to that effect. Once I completed that It began to POP mail from my exchange server.

At some point during all of this Google sent me another email asking me to click on a link and this allowed me to send/ receive mail using the account I have on the exchange server.

I then tested it by sending an email to a completely different account I have on a completely different mail server. Message received and it said it was sent using my account on the exchange server. I hit reply and it was received in the Gmail interface.

I am sending email directly through my Exchange server using smtp from a gmail interface. I am receiving email directly from my exchange server to the same gmail interface using pop3. I can both send and receive as the user account I have on the same exchange server and do this with the gmail interface..

So it works for me. try those steps. hit me back if you can't make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. FYI, on my end there is no «Accounts and Import», it's «Accounts», anyways ...  at this step: «So click on "Add another Email Address" first» I enter the EoL email address and click «Next Step» and I get, in the same dialog window:
[Functionality not enabled.]
You must send through mydomainname.ca SMTP servers when you send as fmonroe@mydomainname.ca.  However, this functionality is not available for your account. 
Please contact your domain administrator for more information. 
As indicated in the question, I am trying to connect to Exchange on Line (EoL). .....

Comment: OK, so its not that it can't be done." However, this functionality is not available for your account". Explains why you cant do it.   However, I am curious as to why you don't have "Accounts and Imports" like I do. I wonder if gmail is offering a slightly different interface for those outside of USA.